# Updating Sagemaker Endpoint with new Endpoint Configuration

Tags: python, endpoint, amazon-sagemaker

A bit confused with automatisation of Sagemaker retraining the model.

Currently I have a notebook instance with Sagemaker `LinearLerner` model making the classification task. So using `Estimator` I'm making training, then deploying the model creating `Endpoint`. Afterwards using `Lambda` function for invoke this endpoint, I add it to the `API Gateway` receiving the api endpoint which can be used for POST requests and sending back response with class.

Now I'm facing with the problem of retraining. For that I use `serverless` approach and `lambda` function getting environment variables for training_jobs. But the problem that Sagemaker not allow to rewrite training job and you can only create new one. My goal is to automatise the part when the new training job and the new endpoint config will apply to the existing endpoint that I don't need to change anything in API gateway. Is that somehow possible to automatically attach new endpoint config with existing endpoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you should be able to use [CreateEndpointConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateEndpointConfig.html) near the end of the training job, then use [UpdateEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateEndpoint.html):

`Deploys the new EndpointConfig specified in the request, switches to using newly created endpoint, and then deletes resources provisioned for the endpoint using the previous EndpointConfig (there is no availability loss).`

If the API Gateway / Lambda is routed via the endpoint ARN, that should not change after using `UpdateEndpoint`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use the `UpdateEndpoint` endpoint. However, if you are using the Python Sagemaker SDK, be aware, there might be some documentation floating around asking you to call

```py
model.deploy(..., update_endpoint=True)
```

This is apparently now deprecated in v2 of the Sagemaker SDK:

You should instead use the `Predictor` [class to perform this update](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/predictors.html):

```py
from sagemaker.predictor import Predictor
predictor = Predictor(endpoint_name="YOUR-ENDPOINT-NAME", sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session_object)
predictor.update_endpoint(instance_type="ml.t2.large", initial_instance_count=1)
```

Comment: one cannot pass a model version in Model Registry to the predictor, so how does the predictor know which model version to use in a Model Package Group?

Comment: @geominded looks like you can pass a ModelPackage name to the `model_name` parameter in `predictor.update_endpoint(..., model_name=model_pkg.name, ...)`.

Comment: ...but while it does trigger an endpoint update, the model does not change -- regardless of the ARN I argue in `model_name`.